# How to get the current location of windows phone without running the app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

I have developed a windows phone app that sends notification to users. There is a cloud service that send notification via mspn and an app running on windows phone. My cloud service will send notification based on current location of the phone . The app running in windows phone needs to register the current location of the device on cloud service every 12 hours. My app wont be running 24hour. So how can i update the device's position after every 12 hours? Can i run my app in background? Has anyone faced a similar situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run Periodic Agent in the background. More info can be fount on MSDN:

- [Background Agents Overview for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)
- [How to: Implement Background Agents for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202941%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

When you want use GeoCoordinateWatcher inside your background agent you have to know about some limits:

> This API, used for obtaining the geographic coordinates of the device,
>   is supported for use in background agents, but it uses a cached
>   location value instead of real-time data. The cached location value is
>   updated by the device every 15 minutes.